# How to declare multiple variables with type annotation syntax in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

As far as I know, now we can declare variables using type annotation syntax in Python 3.6 as following code.

```
def printInt():
    a: int = 0
    b: int = 1
    c: int = 2
    print(a, b, c)
```

What I want to do is declaring variables `a`, `b`, `c` in one line.

I tried `a, b, c: int`, but it returns error.

Also `a: int=0, b: int=1, c: int=2` returns error too.

Is there any way to declare multiple variables using type annotation syntax in one line?

Comment: Well there really isn't static typing in the sense you want, the type annotations syntax may not support this case. There's always semicolons to put multiple lines on one line, but I feel like that's not what you are asking about?

Comment: @shuttle87 Well I was also talking about the type annotation. What I'm asking is how to assign values to multiple variables in one-line using type annotation syntax.

Comment: If you really asked just about 'how to assign values to multiple variable in one-line' your question is way of. In Python you assign values to variables. that's why you can't do `a, b c` you have to assign them as `a,b,c=0,1,2`

Comment: @sdf3w yes, I understood you were talking about type annotations, currently I don't think multiple independent variables can be annotated on a single line: https://repl.it/repls/HelpfulTornBracket I'd like to do this myself in a couple of projects but I don't think it's possible (yet)

Comment: @shuttle87 So it seems it's not possible yet in current python implementation.. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

If you really want to use annotation then
you can do this in this form:-

```
a: int;b: int;c: int
a,b,c = range(3)
print(a,b,c) #As output 0 1 2
```

Answer (score 5):

```
 a: int = 0; b: int = 1; c: int = 2
```

would actually work.
If you are looking for a way to avoid repeating `int` all times, I am afraid you cannot as of Python 3.7.

Answer (score 0):

Commas are not allowed and will yield a syntax error. You can't use the regular one liner:

```py
a, b, c = 0, 1, 2
```

The workarounds would work in any python version with typing support:

```py
a: int; b: int; c: int; a, b, c = 0, 1, 2
```

```py
a: int = 0; b: int = 1; c: int = 2
```

---

It does not apply to your question but this would work too in some cases:

```py
abc: tuple[int] = (0, 1, 2)
```

Answer (score -8):

Python is completely object oriented, and not "statically typed". You do not need to declare variables before using them, or declare their type. Every variable in Python is an object.

```
a,b,c=0,1,2
```

Or the following maybe what you are looking for

```
def magic(a: str, b: str) -> int:
    light = a.find(b)
    return light
```

Comment: Sorry for making question unclear. What I was talking about type annotation syntax actually, not static typing. I edited my question.

Comment: Edited my answer, let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: @Longroadahead No unfortunately it doesn't. He is asking about declaring and annotating multiple variables in a single line. Not sure what you were answering to.